# ORA-01403: no data found for inserting data with trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am creating following table in the SQL Developer environment in Oracle:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_cust (
    cust_id         VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
    cust_name       VARCHAR2(50),
    created_date    DATE DEFAULT sysdate,
    trusted         CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N',
    ind_id          VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
    emp_id          VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
    cust_scont_id   VARCHAR2(4),
    cust_pcont_id   VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE tbl_cust
    ADD CHECK ( trusted IN (
        'N',
        'Y'
    ) );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tbl_cust__idx ON
    tbl_cust (
        cust_pcont_id
    ASC );

ALTER TABLE tbl_cust ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_cust_pk PRIMARY KEY ( cust_id );
```

Then, I am trying to create a following trigger for the table;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TRUSTED_CUSTOMER
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON tbl_cust 
    FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE
    v_no_of_days number;

BEGIN
    IF (:new.cust_id is not null AND UPPER(:NEW.TRUSTED) = 'Y')  THEN
    --SELECT to_number(to_date(sysdate, 'dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date(c.created_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')) INTO v_no_of_days
    SELECT to_number(to_date(TRUNC(sysdate), 'dd-mm-yyyy') - to_date(c.created_date, 'dd-mm-yyyy')) INTO v_no_of_days
    FROM tbl_cust c
    WHERE c.cust_id = :new.cust_id;
            IF (v_no_of_days  <= 365)   THEN
            raise_application_error(-20022, 'The customer is not trusted yet');
            END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

And when I am trying to insert the following data

```
INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id, cust_name, created_date, trusted, ind_id, emp_id, cust_scont_id, cust_pcont_id) 
VALUES ('C500', 'GOODMAN', '01-DEC-19', 'Y', 'IN03', 'E005','SA05', 'PA05');
```

I am getting this error

> ```
> Error starting at line : 26 in command -
> INSERT INTO tbl_cust(cust_id, cust_name, created_date, trusted, ind_id, emp_id, cust_scont_id, cust_pcont_id) 
> VALUES ('C500', 'GOODMAN', '01-DEC-19', 'Y', 'IN03', 'E005','SA05', 'PA05')
> Error report -
> ORA-01403: no data found
> ORA-06512: at "TTAPADAR.TRG_TRUSTED_CUSTOMER", line 7
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'TTAPADAR.TRG_TRUSTED_CUSTOMER'
> ```

Any help will much appreciated.

Comment: When you subtract a DATE from a DATE then result is a number, so `to_number` is useless. Then `SYSDATE` and `created_date` are already `DATE` thus `to_date` is also useless. **Never** call `TO_DATE` on a value which is already a `DATE`. Simply run `TRUNC(sysdate) - c.created_date`

Comment: However, in your INSERT you should better use `TO_DATE`, i.e. `TO_DATE('01-DEC-19', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')` - or even better: `TO_DATE('01-DEC-2019', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN')`

Comment: If `created_date` is a `date` column you should specify an [actual date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1), not `'01-DEC-19'`. Possibly you could set the column default as `default on null trunc(sysdate)` if you want the current date in every new row.

Comment: Also, `trusted` should be a normal string, not `char(1)`.

Comment: Also, PL/SQL `if` conditions don't need brackets because they are terminated by `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rearrange as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_TRUSTED_CUSTOMER
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON tbl_cust
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  v_no_of_days number;

BEGIN
  IF (:new.cust_id is not null AND UPPER(:NEW.TRUSTED) = 'Y') THEN
        v_no_of_days := trunc(sysdate) - :new.created_date;
  END IF;

  IF (v_no_of_days <= 365) THEN
      raise_application_error(-20022, 'The customer is not trusted yet');
  END IF;  
END;
```

trying to insert into table while selecting through `:new.cust_id` which's not inserted yet.

Btw, there might rise a risk of mutating trigger due to selecting from the table on which the trigger was created.